# iOS - What is the equivalent of "stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0"?

Tags: ios, uiimage, image-resizing

What is an equal value of 
 `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` for `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0`?

Also, Is there any simple way to convert the values from `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth` to `resizableImageWithCapInsets`?

Because the `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth` method was deprecated in iOS 5.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess your looking for resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero?

Comment: No.. resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero does not give the same result which the  stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0 gives..

Answer (score 0):

By using:

```
stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0
```

You're telling iOS that *you want the entire image to be vertically stretchable* **and** *you want the entire image to also be horizontally stretchable* (itals copied directly from Apple docs).  In other words, no part of the image will be preserved unstretched.

In converting your code to use the new method introduced in iOS 5, though, you'll have to keep in mind that **the new method works differently than the old one when it determines how to resize the image not contained in the caps** (hence the move away from using "stretch" in the method name itself).

While the old method used pure (and not always efficient) scaling of every pixel not contained in the caps as a whole, the new method defaults to the more efficient tiling approach. As a consequence, the results between old and new methods **will be very different** if the part of the image you're stretching (the part not contained in the caps) measures more than one pixel in the direction(s) being stretched **and isn't uniform**.

While you have not provided screenshots of the actual image you are working with or the results you're getting, which makes it impossible to tell you exactly why you're not getting the results you want, it does sound like you specifically want your image to be resized with the `UIImageResizingModeStretch` resizing mode (rather than the default tiling mode). If so, it's likely that you should be using this method instead:

```
resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets resizingMode:
```

The answer to your second question also depends on how you want the stretchable part of your image stretched.

Heuristically:

- If your old caps were non-zero and the portion being stretched was either 1x1 pixel or at least uniform in the direction(s) of stretching, you'd probably be able to use `UIEdgeInsetsMake(*top*, *left*, *bottom*, *right*)` with your LeftCap value as left and right and your TopCap value as top and bottom, given that the old method assumed you wanted to stretch the image symmetrically.
- If your old caps were 0 or the portion being stretched was larger than 1x1 pixel in any direction(s) of resized and non-uniform, you could still convert the caps in the same way but you'd want to use the method variant that allows you to control the resizingMode.